Port forwarding raspberry pi on home GPON nokia g-2425g-a doesn't work
I have a nokia G-2425G-A modem at home from my ISP and I installed home assistant on my raspberry pi. For accessing it outside my local network, there is a service called "duck DNS" which needs the raspberry pi to be forwarded to the port 8123. When I tried to set up my ISP modem to port forward like this:
GPON config
I went to "canyouseeme.org" but it didn't detect the port (Connection timed out). I even checked that the port was 8123 and not other, but nothing. Can anyone tell me if I messed up any configuration?

Are you by chance behind a CGNAT?

How can I know that? I just searched and it says that depending on your IP and your ISP modem's IP, and both are different, in case that means there is CGNAT.
